# How to combine two numpy arrays with different dimemsions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays as follows:

```
a=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b=np.array([[3,4],[1,2],[3,4]])
```

I would like a result :

```
np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[3,4],[1,2],[3,4]]])
```

I tried `np.concatenate` and `np.stack`, but the first is not workable and the second is really slow.
How to solve this faster?

Comment: Can't you just start with one and loop through the other adding each item to first array?

Comment: @ SANM2009 You mean use np.append? How

Comment: @Cleb The result is array([array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]]),
       array([[3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4]])], dtype=object)

Comment: dimension is (2,)

Comment: @ZHANGJuenjie The shapes are not compatible, so numpy cannot create a contiguous array from these sub-arrays. In other words, the array is stored as an array of objects, each object being a list. This is pointless to have from a numpy perspective. You may as well just keep them in a python list.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ very true

Comment: @J. C. Rocamonde. By the way, do you mean that the data I feed into a tensorflow graph should have to have the same shape of a same batch?

Comment: @J. C. Rocamonde. I plan to feed this into a graph calculation. Seems it is not possible to make these two in one batch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
import numpy as np 
r = np.array([np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]), np.array([[5,6],[7,8]])])
print(r)
```

As @COLDSPEED points out, the result won’t be exactly what you expect since from a dataset perspective it is pointless to store rows with different dimensions. That is why the result is something like a list of arrays. This might be an indicator that the approach you are trying to do with your workflow is not perfectly adequate. Maybe you could try and re-think your data model.

Comment: array([array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]]),
       array([[3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [3, 4]])], dtype=object)

Comment: I have two array

Comment: Isn’t it the same?

Comment: If I type the shape it is (2,)

Comment: The dimensions of your expected result are also 2

Comment: Sorry, it maybe the same, but just two array not so satisfying

Comment: It is not about **satisfaction**, this is not a painting. What is the difference with what you expect?

Comment: Like, does it not suit your needs? Maybe I can find an alternative solution

Comment: @ I want a result like this array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[3, 4], [1, 2], [3, 4]]])

Comment: But it seems these are equal. Do you have any other solutions?

Comment: If they are equal why another solution?

Comment: C. Rocamomde.That is fine

Comment: @ J. C. Rocamonde Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161626/discussion-between-zhang-juenjie-and-j-c-rocamonde).